# How to upload an app to the Play Store for the second time? you already have one with version code 1 error

Tags: android, expo, react-native, google-play-console

I was sucessfully uploading my apk to the play store in branch internal testing and suddently, it started to refuse my new apk with this error:

```
You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1.
```

[image]

This is my `app.json` used by expo for generating the manifest:

```
{
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myapp.www",
      "versionCode": 360010305,
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA_ROLL",
        "CAMERA",
        "LOCATION",
        "NOTIFICATIONS",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ]
    }
}
```

I use [this](https://github.com/byCedric/semantic-release-expo/issues/4#issuecomment-417583573) since I have installed `semantic-release-expo` which take care of updating the `app.json` for me upon each new release.

Since [the default](https://github.com/byCedric/semantic-release-expo#version-templates-variables) is already `code`, I wonder why I still got this error, perhaps I should change this setting to increment and set the `versionCode` to 1 ?

Why I am not allowed anymore to publish the builded apk (on expo's CIs) to the PlayStore anymore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem did arrive with expo SDK36, removign the `sdkVersion`  from `package.json` and causing `expo-semantic-release` to not update the `versionNumber` of the android application.

This was fixed by adding in my expo configuration `app.json`:

```
{
  "expo": {
+    "sdkVersion": "38.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with version code. Play store detects previous or same version code in your code. So Just Replace your version code with 360010306. After that may resolve your issue.

Comment: I use [this](https://github.com/byCedric/semantic-release-expo/issues/4#issuecomment-417583573) since I have installed `semantic-release-expo` which take care of updating the `app.json` for me upon each new release.

Comment: Since [the default](https://github.com/byCedric/semantic-release-expo#version-templates-variables) is already `code`, I wonder why I still got this error, perhaps I should change this setting to increment and set the `versionCode` to 11 ?

Comment: (Example) If you give last version 100 in the play store, after that you not used 1-100 again. So maybe you used any of those versions. So if you used 101 of your version code that time it's ok and updated in google play store.

Comment: I never published on the play store to public people, I only deployed once in internal testing and I was the only testeur and it was the only version, I can see it in the dashboard

Comment: For some reason, it is tagged as version 1 while the repo use a longer  verrsion  And semantic-release does not update the file, do you know how?

Comment: Play store not accepted any previous version for published apk. I face this problem and I remove it with increasing version code.

Comment: You can see for details. https://medium.com/@maxirosson/versioning-android-apps-d6ec171cfd82

Answer (score 1):

Update the **version code** in your project if it was 1 **increase** to 2 and so on
then generate new **APK** and upload it again to the *console*.

Comment: I am not supposed to deal with versionning since I installed semantic-release I don't get why expo-semantic-release does not update the `versionCode` automatically like for ios or web version.

Comment: i thought you are using **android studio**

Answer (score 0):

Update your Build.gradle to:

```
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yourpackage"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 360010306
        versionName "0.8.8-Alpha"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
...
```

For each .aab or .apk file to upload on the console the VersionCode must be different and this number is limited to 2100000000... value.

Specifically in your case, you need to up to your version code to next natural number... But, you must be careful with use random numbers to version, the pattern is elevate number one per one.